django asgi raised django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet
I want to build a Django app with django-channels.
But when I run the following command:
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8010 paya.asgi:application

It gives me this error: Apps aren't loaded yet.
This error occurs when I add the following line to the consumer.py:
from Auth.models import Store

consumers.py:
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from Auth.models import Store

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['sender']
        self.store = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['receiver']
        self.user_store_group = f'store_{self.user}_{self.store}'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.user_store_group,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()
        #self.sotreUser = Store.objects.get(id=self.store)
        #data = [json.dumps({'name': 1, 'productId': 2, 'receiver': self.sotreUser.user.username})]
        #self.send(text_data=data)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        print(text_data)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'add_order',
                'message': text_data_json
            }
        )

    def add_order(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))

asgi.py:
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.urls import path
from chat.consumers import *

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            [path('ws/chat/<str:sender>/<str:receiver>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),]
        )
    ),
})

setting.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'paya.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = { 'default': { 'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer', 'CONFIG': { "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)], }, },}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'NAME',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

this command:
sudo tail -f /var/log/daphne.err.log
raised this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
] 

can u try this
